# MessageEmbed author name must be a string

Tags: javascript, discord

I've tried to create an embed message on Discord base on [this discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview), and ran into this problem:

```
RangeError [EMBED_AUTHOR_NAME]: MessageEmbed author name must be a string.
    at Function.verifyString (D:\Kien Thuc\IT\HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:413:41)
    at MessageEmbed.setAuthor (D:\Kien Thuc\IT\HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:356:32)
    at Object.execute (D:\Kien Thuc\IT\HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT\DiscordBot\commands\example-embed.js:16:14)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\Kien Thuc\IT\HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT\DiscordBot\index.js:24:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (D:\Kien Thuc\IT\HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:70:12)
bsocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\Kien Thuc\IT\HTML CSS JAVASCRIPT\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10) {  [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_AUTHOR_NAME'
}
```

Here's my code:

```js
const {
    SlashCommandBuilder
} = require('@discordjs/builders');
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('embeds')
        .setDescription('embeds'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Some title')
            .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
            .setAuthor({
                name: 'Some name',
                iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png',
                url: 'https://discord.js.org'
            })
            .setDescription('Some description here')
            .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
            .addFields({
                name: 'Regular field title',
                value: 'Some value here'
            }, {
                name: '\u200B',
                value: '\u200B'
            }, {
                name: 'Inline field title',
                value: 'Some value here',
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Inline field title',
                value: 'Some value here',
                inline: true
            }, )
            .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
            .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png');
        await interaction.reply({
            embeds: [exampleEmbed]
        });
    },
};
```

I just don't understand, the key "name" here has a string value: 'some name', so why can't it run?
My temporary solution here is to wipe out that Author part and the code runs smooth as heck.

Comment: I'm assuming `setAuthor` expects a string parameter, not an object. So something like `setAuthor('Some name')`

Comment: Good to see your opinion, I guess the embed constructor on discordjs.guide is outdated, so I changed to embed object, thanks 

Comment: @MattU Actually not entirely true. They changed it in the latest dev builds, so it will be mandatory to use an object. But since you got that error, I'm guessing that SaberToaster is not even on the latest stable version of discord.js. (Tbh this changed in V 13.5, which was released 15 days ago. The change was made here explicitly: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/commit/3496516dc99149705754ed56f3e9dfe711d3926d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue - what fixed it for me was removing the {} inside of .setAuthor() as well as omitting `name:`, `iconURL:`, and `url:`.

So, it would look like this:

`.setAuthor('Some name','https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png','https://discord.js.org')`